# Maximum likelihood for joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I would like to fit a distribution $f(\cdot;\theta)$ to a sample $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, obtaining a m.l.e. $\hat{\theta}$. I know that the random variable $X \sim f(\cdot;\theta)$ can be obtained as the result of generating a random variable $Y$ following a distribution with p.d.f. $g(\cdot;\theta)$ and then generating $X$ following a distribution with p.d.f. $h(\cdot;Y)$.

Is it the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\theta}$ obtained by maximizing $\theta$ in
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i; \theta)
$$
equal to the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\theta}$ obtained by maximizing $(\theta, y_1, \dots, y_n)$ in
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n g(y_i; \theta) h(x_i; y_i)?
$$

(I didn't know whether to ask the question here or in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280465/maximum-likelihood-estimate-for-a-compound-distribution). I included the question in both sites)

Comment: Do the observed data contain both the $x$s and the $y$s or only the $x$s?

Comment: Only $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ are observed.

Comment: ok, Then that complicates things. If you observed $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ then then $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ wouldn't even need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't observe $y_i$, you have this density for $X_i{:}$
$$
\int_{\large\mathscr Y} h(x_i;y) g(y;\theta) \, dy
$$
(where $\mathscr Y$ is the space of possible $y$ values).

Therefore the likelihood function is
$$
L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \int_{\large\mathscr Y} h(x_i;y) g(y;\theta) \, dy.
$$

Comment: Yes, as you say, $f$ can be written as an integral of the product of $g$ and $h$. I am only interested in knowing if parameter $\theta$ remains the same whether I optimize $f$ (maybe in closed form or maybe not) or $g h$

Comment: If for each value of $\theta$ the distribution is the same then you will get the same MLE, because $$f(x_i;\theta) = \int_{\large\mathscr Y} h(x_i;y) g(y;\theta) \, dy. $$